# How to give a universal value option?

Tags: reactjs

Which attribute to use in option so that when you click on it, get the value in the onChange event?

```
function App() {
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select
        value={category}
        onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
          setCategory(value);
        }}
      >
        <option ?={"1"}>{"Black"}</option>
        <option ?={"2"}>{"White"}</option>
        <option ?={"3"}>{"Pink"}</option>
        <option ?={"4"}>{"Red"}</option>
        <option ?={"5"}>{"Gray"}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: i think you have to set a state or set the onChange event on each option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute you need to use for the `option` element is the normal `value` attribute.

```
<option value={"1"}>{"Black"}</option>
```

The only special addition React added to the `select` element was the ability to use `value` to set the selected option and not needing to manually assign the `selected` attribute to the `option` elements.

Source: [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag)

Comment: And if I want to get the value inside the option, I have to do it like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/m4zv91xn4x)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how it should be with the standard `select` element.